# Estimate delta and vega using ”likelihood ratio method” for an Asian Option

Tags: python, montecarlo

Let S(0) = 100, K ∈ {80, 100, 120}, r = 0.03 and  = 20% and 0 = 0 < 1 < ⋯ <  = 1 where  − −1 = 1/ for  ∈ {12, 52}. Using 20 000 simulations, Estimate delta and vega using ”likelihood ratio method”

the code is below:

I got this error when i run the code can you rearrange the code?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-f939e5735d40> in <cell line: 36>()
     36 for i in range(2):
     37     # Calculate Delta using the likelihood ratio method
---> 38     delta[i] = np.exp(-r * T) * (mean_S[i] > K) * (Z[i][:, -1] / (S0 * sigma * np.sqrt(T / m[i])))
     39 
     40     # Calculate Vega using the likelihood ratio method

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20000,3) (20000,)
```

```
S0 = 100
K = np.array([80, 100, 120]).reshape(1, 3)
r = 0.03
sigma = 0.2
T = 1
m = np.array([12, 52])
number_of_sim = 20000
h = np.array([1, 0.01])
dt = 1 / m

time_step = {0: np.arange(dt[0], T + dt[0], dt[0]).reshape(1, m[0])}
S = {0: np.zeros((number_of_sim, m[0]))}
Z = {0: np.random.standard_normal((number_of_sim, m[0]))}
delta = {0: np.zeros((1, 3))}
vega = {0: np.zeros((1, 3))}

for i in range(1, 2):
    time_step[i] = np.arange(dt[i], T + dt[i], dt[i]).reshape(1, m[1])
    Z[i] = np.random.standard_normal((number_of_sim, m[i]))
    S[i] = np.zeros((number_of_sim, m[i]))
    delta[i] = np.zeros((1, 3))
    vega[i] = np.zeros((1, 3))

for i in range(2):
    S[i][:, 0] = S0 * np.exp((r - 0.5 * sigma**2) * dt[i] + np.sqrt(dt[i]) * sigma * Z[i][:, 0])

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(m[i] - 1):
        S[i][:, j + 1] = S[i][:, j] * np.exp((r - 0.5 * sigma**2) * dt[i] + np.sqrt(dt[i]) * sigma * Z[i][:, j + 1])

mean_S = {0: np.mean(S[0], axis=1).reshape(number_of_sim, 1), 1: np.mean(S[1], axis=1).reshape(number_of_sim, 1)}

delta = {0: np.zeros((1, 3)), 1: np.zeros((1, 3))}
vega = {0: np.zeros((1, 3)), 1: np.zeros((1, 3))}

for i in range(2):
    # Calculate Delta using the likelihood ratio method
    delta[i] = np.exp(-r * T) * (mean_S[i] > K) * (Z[i][:, -1] / (S0 * sigma * np.sqrt(T / m[i])))
    
    # Calculate Vega using the likelihood ratio method
    vega[i] = np.exp(-r * T) * (mean_S[i] > K) * np.sum((Z[i]**2 - 1) / sigma - Z[i] * np.sqrt(time_step[i][0, 1:]), axis=1) / S0

strikes = ['K = 80', 'K = 100', 'K = 120']

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['Delta (LRM)', 'Vega (LRM)'], columns=strikes)

for i in range(3):
    df.loc['Delta (LRM)', strikes[i]] = round(delta[0][i], 3)
    df.loc['Vega (LRM)', strikes[i]] = round(vega[0][i], 3)

display(Markdown("#### Asian call m = 12"))
display(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=['Delta (LRM)', 'Vega (LRM)'], columns=strikes)

for i in range(3):
    df2.loc['Delta (LRM)', strikes[i]] = round(delta[1][i], 3)
    df2.loc['Vega (LRM)', strikes[i]] = round(vega[1][i], 3)

display(Markdown("#### Asian call m = 52"))
display(df2)
```